# Delphi 10 Seattle crash when I click on Options > Provisioning

Tags: xcode, delphi, provisioning-profile, delphi-10-seattle, paserver

When I click on the **Options > Provisioning** menu, Delphi seems to connect to PAServer, then quickly show 3 errors messages :

**Rad Studio stopped working**

then :

**EOSError exception in module rtl230.bpl at 0004DC21.**

**System error. Code : 5.**

**Access denied.**

then :

**Access violation in module valid230.bpl**

Any idea ?

I've tried to stop PAServer before showing the Provisioning panel. Delphi show warning message 'connection has failed', but doesn't crash !

My config :

- Windows 10 Professional
- Rad Studio 10 Seattle (Delphi) run as Administrator
- Connection profile is working
- No project opened within the IDE
- Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 - Clean install
- Xcode 7.1.1
- PAServer 17 Hotfix (for OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.1) is running

Comment: Please try restarting your Mac and Windows PC. Sometimes that just appears to be necessary.

Comment: If this is a bug in the product you should just provide steps and report it at Quality Central : https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Subscription Update 1 seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Subscription Update 1 seems to work properly.